# Sorting MongoDB data by Year

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using Node.js to make a dashboard that displays different charts about different economy variables for different countries. I am getting the information from a mongodb database, and I have to format it in a specific way so that the chart (using Highcharts) can be made; I am having trouble with the **line chart**. The format is through a name variable and the data points in an array, for example name: France, GDP: [8, 5, 13, 11]. I am able to get this with no trouble through this code.

```
var Country = require('../models/country');
    Country.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        name: { $in: ["USA", "China", "India", "France", "Japan"]},
      }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$name',
            nominalGDP: {$push: "$nominalGDP"}
      }
    }, 
    {
        $project: {
        _id: 0,
        name: "$_id",
        nominalGDP: 1
        }
    }
  ], function(err, recs){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(recs);
    }
});
```

In this, I have a schema, Country, and I am using the aggregate feature of mongoose. I $match the different countries I want. Then I group my countries by their name; this is important because I basically threw all my countries and information into one collection. Thus, I can have 3 different rows for USA, one for 2015, one for 2016, and one for 2017. Because of this, I have to group them by name and then $push the nominalGDP for each so that it can be an array. The only problem I have now is ensuring that they get pushed into the array correctly in ascending order from 2015 to 2017, rather than in random order that it does now. What is the best way for achieving this? Please let me know if I need to provide any more details.

Btw I had to build my schema this way since I have an upload feature where a schema gets built automatically from an import/upload of a csv file. Making it to where I have two tables, one for the country names and another for their year and year data, would be difficult for me since I followed a tutorial for my current way lol

Comment: Have you tried using `$sort` ? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

Comment: Would I be able to sort if I do not even retrieve the years?

Comment: Can you add a sample document from your collection with expected json response ? Try adding sort before group. `{$sort:{year:1}}`

Comment: In the same table? yes. If you need it to work on different table you would need to `$lookup` first.

Comment: oh man it worked that was easy lol y'all are fantastic